# Nested loops with arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to answer equal sides of an array on code wars.

The challenge is to create a function, that when given an array, will find if two sides of an array when added up have the same value.

E.g [4,7,3,9,2]
the function would return 2. 4+7 = 11 and 9+2 = 11, 3 is in the middle and the index of the 3 is 2

[9,3,9,7,8,-2] => again 2 (9)

[1,2,3,4] doesnt have so => -1

```
function findEvenIndex(arr)
{
  //Code goes here!
var rightSum = 0
var leftSum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){


 for(var x = i+1; x<arr.length; x++){
       rightSum += +arr[x];
  }

 for(var y = i-1; y>0; y--){
   leftSum += arr[y];
  }


 if(leftSum == rightSum){
   return arr.indexOf(arr[i])
 }
}
if(leftSum != rightSum){return -1}

}
```

I am really stuck on this.
My rightSum values and leftSum values add up  each time the loop is called. So they end up being a high value.

How do I fix this?

Sorry I had a really hard time explaing this :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider revising your question to make sure that you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people are able to help you. Try to explain the *problem at hand*, *your result*, and the *expected result*.

Comment: I don't have codewars account to view your link. And I am not creating an account to view your link. Even if I have an account, I don't want to sign in to view your link. Or IF I am already signed in to codewars, I don't really want to click your link. Please help.

Comment: For the sake of yourself and others, I recommend you indent and format your code. For debugging tips, see http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: You give `[9,3,9,7,8,-2] => again 2 (9)` as an example. Yet 9+3=12, while 7+8=2 is 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you walk through the program in your head, stating out loud what each line is supposed to do and how it is supposed to work. You could also run the program by hand to make sure it does what you want. Or, you could use a debugger to walk through the program step by step, examining variables. If you don't know how to use a debugger, stop everything else you are doing and learn that. Anyway, here are some comments on your code:

```
function findEvenIndex(arr)
{
  //Code goes here!
```

Remove extraneous comments from your code.

```
  var rightSum = 0
```

Do yourself and everyone else a favor by indenting your code properly. The most 
common indentation style is two spaces.

The most common style is to use semicolons. I suggest you follow that; there are some good reasons to. But whichever you choose, be consistent!

```
  var leftSum = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){

    for(var x = i+1; x<arr.length; x++){
      rightSum += +arr[x];
```

You are incrementing `rightSum`. That's fine, but the previous value of `rightSum`, from the previous time through the outside loop, will still be there. You'll be incrementing that. That's not what you want. You need to initialize `rightSum` and `leftSum` back to zero **within** the outside loop.

```
    }

    for(var y = i-1; y>0; y--){
      leftSum += arr[y];
    }

    if(leftSum == rightSum){
      return arr.indexOf(arr[i])
```

This is quite weird. You already have the index--it is `i`--and you are trying to find the index of the value at the index you already know? This will also fail if an earlier element happens to have the same value as this element. So this should just be `return i;`.

```
    }
  }

  if(leftSum != rightSum){return -1}
```

By the time you get here, you know there is no solution. Of course `leftSum` and `righSum` will not be equal, because they weren't the last time through the loop. In other words, you do not need the if, just `return -1;`.

#### Another approach

But as usual, there are many ways to simplify this. One would be to use `slice`, which is a handy way to take subsets of arrays. We'll also use `sum`, a little routine we're going to write right now. It's often helpful to break out little bits of logic and package them up as functions. It makes your code more readable and understandable.

```
function sum(arr) { 
  var s = 0; 
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) s += arr[i];
  return s;
}
```

Now we will follow the same basic top-level structure as your program, looping over `i`:

```
function findEvenIndex(arr)
{
  for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    IF LEFTSIDE === RIGHTSIDE return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

To create the left side, we can use the array function `slice`, like this:

```
arr.slice(0, i)
```

This will take the first `i` elements of `arr`--in other words, elements with indices `0` through `i-1`. To create the right side, we again use `slice`:

```
arr.slice(i+1)
```

which takes the elements starting at `i+1` through the end. Since we already have our handy `sum` function, we can just say:

```
if (sum(arr.slice(0, i)) === sum(arr.slice(i+1))) return i;
```

and we are done.

To make the program more semantic and easier to read and think about, we can put this logic in a separate function, returning true or false:

```
function isEvenIndex(elt, idx, arr) {
  return sum(arr.slice(0, idx)) === sum(arr.slice(idx+1));
}
```

Why have we chosen to use parameters of `elt`, `idx`, and `arr`, when we don't even use `elt`? Well, this is a classic signature for the callbacks passed to various array functions such as `forEach`, and this will make things easier later when we use this as a callback to `findIndex`--see below.

Now our entire program is just

```
function findEvenIndex(arr)
{
  for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (isEvenIndex(arr[i], i, arr)) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Once you've boiled down your program like this, it becomes much harder for bugs to slip in!

But is there some better way to handle the loop over the array looking for a particular condition? Yes, this is the exact purpose of the new `find` and `findIndex` functions on arrays. We pass these methods a function, which is called for each element in the array, and the result is the first element, or index, for which the function returns true. The function is passed as parameters the element itself (which we don't need here), the index, and the array, just as we have defined `isEvenIndex`. If the callback function doesn't return true for any element, then `findIndex` returns -1, just like we want, so we don't have to worry about that any more. Our entire program is now the following (taking a slightly different approach to `sum`):

```
function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
  function sum(arr)  { return arr.reduce(add); }
  function isEvenIndex(elt, idx, arr) {
    return sum(arr.slice(0, idx)) === sum(arr.slice(idx+1));
  }

  return arr.findIndex(isEvenIndex);
}
```

You can write this slightly more compactly using ES6 arrow functions:

```
function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  var add    = (a, b) => a + b;
  var sum    = a => a.reduce(add, 0);
  var isEven = (e, i, a) => sum(a.slice(0, i)) === sum(a.slice(i+1));

  return arr.findIndex(isEven);
}
```

Once you begin to program like this, you'll find both that your code is easier to write and read and maintain, for you and others who come after you, and also that there is much less room for annoying bugs to creep in.

#### Getting from here to there

How do you migrate toward this style of programming? Here are some prerequisites:

1. You have to know the methods that we used, such as `reduce`, `slice`, and `findIndex`. Study the documentation for array methods, such as found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype).
2. You need to discipline yourself to relentlessly look for common aspects of your code, and "factor" them out. For instance, if you find you are adding up the elements of an array twice, as in your original code, then "factor out" the notion of calculating the sum of the elements of an array into a separate `sum` function.
3. You can adopt a more top-down design style, using placeholders or pseudo-code for the internal details, which you fill in later.

Comment: return arr.indexOf(arr[i]) This is also problematic because of duplicates. Check my answer for an example case.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer! I wrote this question on my phone so sorry about the indentation. Again thanks alot.

Comment: I will place a bounty and award it to you when I can.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 problems with your code (ignoring the fact that your approach may not be the most optimal approach):

Since your rightSum and leftSum are not cleared after every iteration, you are noticing that the last value stays over in the next iteration. This should be:

```
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
  var rightSum = 0 // rightSum and leftSum gets initialized for each iteration
  var leftSum = 0;

  for(var x = i+1; x<arr.length; x++){
    rightSum += +arr[x];
  }
```

Another problem is this:

```
   return arr.indexOf(arr[i])
```

If there are multiple instances of the same number, this will return the first occurence of the number.
For eg. if the array is [10,10,10]. Even though the answer is 1, your function will return 0.
This should be replaced by

```
return i;
```

The final code should look something like

```
function findEvenIndex(arr)
{
  //Code goes here!

for(var i = 1; i<arr.length - 1; i++){
var rightSum = 0
var leftSum = 0;

 for(var x = i+1; x<arr.length; x++){
       rightSum += +arr[x];
  }

 for(var y = i-1; y>=0; y--){
   leftSum += arr[y];
  }


 if(leftSum === rightSum){
   return i
 }
}
return -1

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, i assume that you are not able to find the index of the element whose right sum and left sum are equal.

```
function findEvenIndex(arr)
{
var rightSum = 0
var leftSum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    for(var x = i+1; x<arr.length; x++)
    {
        rightSum += arr[x]; //Earlier there was a syntax error here. Extra + was included in your code.
    }

    for(var y = i-1; y>=0; y--)
    { //Indexing starts from 0 and to include the first element on the left, 0 also should be included to get the sum. Earlier = was missing
        leftSum += arr[y];
    } 

    if(leftSum == rightSum)
    {
        return i; //If l.sum and r.sum are equal, return the value
    }       
    leftSum = 0;
    rightSum = 0;
}
return -1;
}
```

Comment: The extra `+` is not necessary, but neither it is a syntax error. And why would you initialize `rightSum` etc. once before the loop and again at the end of each iteration, instead of just at the beginning of each iteration?